# tikz foreeach list is empty?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I' m trying to make an animation with the following code

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\section{Bilder}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[pedestrian/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick},
transition/.style={rectangle,draw=black!50,fill=black!20,thick}]
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin]  (-6,0) grid (3,1) ;

\let\mylist\empty
\foreach \x[count=\i] in {1,...,5}{
\node<\i> [gray,above] at (-7,0.2) {$step=\i$};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\y{6-\i}
\foreach \x in {1,...,\y}
\node<\i>  at  (-6.5+\x, 0.5) [pedestrian] {\tiny{\x,\i,\y|\mylist}};

\ifx\mylist\empty
\xdef\mylist{5};
\else
\foreach \z in \mylist{
\node<\i> at  (-2.5+\i , 0.5) [pedestrian] {\tiny{\z}};
 }    
\xdef\mylist{\y,\mylist};
\fi
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Something is wrong with the variable `z` which is alway 5. I checked the values of `mylist`, which keeps growing, but still... `z` is always  5 (the last element of the list).

Here is the result that I was expecting: [PDF-FILE](https://transfer.sh/7NxJL/tikz.pdf)

I got it by doing some stupid copy-paste

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\section{Bilder}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[pedestrian/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick},
transition/.style={rectangle,draw=black!50,fill=black!20,thick}]
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin]  (-6,0) grid (3,1) ;

\uncover<1>{
\node [gray,above] at (-7,0.2) {$step=0$};
\foreach \x in {1,...,5}
\node  at  (-6.5+\x + 0, 0.5) [pedestrian] {\tiny{\x}};
}

\uncover<2>{
\node [gray,above] at (-7,0.2) {$i=5$};
\foreach \x in {1,...,4}
\node  at  (-6.5+\x + 0, 0.5) [pedestrian] {\tiny{\x}};

\node  at  (-6.5+6 + 0, 0.5) [pedestrian] {\tiny{5}};
}

\uncover<3>{
\node [gray,above] at (-7,0.2) {$i=4$};
\foreach \x in {1,...,3}
\node  at  (-6.5+\x + 0, 0.5) [pedestrian] {\tiny{\x}};

\foreach \x in {4,...,5}
\node  at  (-6.5+1 + \x, 0.5) [pedestrian] {\tiny{\x}};
}
\uncover<4>{
\node [gray,above] at (-7,0.2) {$i=3$};
\foreach \x in {1,...,2}
\node  at  (-6.5+\x + 0, 0.5) [pedestrian] {\tiny{\x}};

\foreach \x in {3,...,5}
\node  at  (-6.5+1 + \x, 0.5) [pedestrian] {\tiny{\x}};

}
\uncover<5>{
\node [gray,above] at (-7,0.2) {$i=2$};

\foreach \x in {2,...,5}
\node  at  (-6.5+1 + \x, 0.5) [pedestrian] {\tiny{\x}};

\node  at  (-6.5 + 1, 0.5) [pedestrian] {\tiny{1}};
}

\uncover<6>{
\node [gray,above] at (-7,0.2) {$i = 1$};

\foreach \x in {1,...,5}
\node  at  (-6.5+1 + \x, 0.5) [pedestrian] {\tiny{\x}};

}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please complete you code to make it compilable. We want an example we can copy-paste-compile to see just the problem you are seeing. That makes it easier to understand and address your question.

Comment: It looks like you have `\let\mylist\empty`, and then you check if it is `\empty` which executes `\xdef\mylist{5}`.  Plus you seem to be missing a `{` after the `\foreach`. Without that _only_ the `\node` is executed, and the `\xdef\mylist{\y,\mylist}` only gets exectuted _after_ the `\foreach` is complete.

Comment: Yes but that happens only once. After that we are in the `else`. Only the `node` should be in `foreach`.

Comment: You are reusing the foreach variable \x twice and at the end not expanding properly. One option `\expandafter\gdef\expandafter\mylist\expandafter{\mylist,\y}%`

Comment: does not help. The problem persists even if i loop over something like `{1,2,3}`. At the end it will be just 3

Comment: What exactly is supposed to happen? My code gets it to *change* but I doubt it changes in the *right way* and I realise that I have no clue what that is.

Comment: It does not matter what it is supposed to do. The point is the last loop is not working (for what reason). I just want to understand why.

Comment: @Tengis: When the last loop works, what is the expected output. How do you know from the output if the last loop worked or not?

Comment: Peter> See the file for the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You example works but you are hit by `beamer` syntax `<i>`

Consider the line change on your last `foreach` loop

```
\node[opacity=0.2] at  (-2.5+\i , 0.5) [pedestrian] {\tiny{\z}};% It was <i> HERE
```

Then we see that the loop is run correctly but because all have the same slide specification `<i>` they got overprinted by the last element which happens to be 5.

[image]

Now we can see that the content is there. You can either try to fix this or you can use a more compact version such as the following (which you can even further code golf it)

```
\documentclass[presentation]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\section{Bilder}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[pedestrian/.style={circle,draw=blue!50,fill=blue!20,thick,font=\tiny},
transition/.style={rectangle,draw=black!50,fill=black!20,thick}]
\draw[step=1cm,gray,very thin]  (-6,0) grid (3,1) ;

\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {5,...,0}{
  \foreach \y[count=\yi from 0] in {1,...,5}{
    \ifnum\yi<\x\relax
      \node<\xi>[pedestrian]  at  (-6.5+\y, 0.5)  {\y};
    \else
      \node<\xi>[pedestrian]  at  (-6.5+\y+1, 0.5)  {\y};
    \fi
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you example works fine. It is even better. That was my first try with tikz (so frustrating) when you don't know the basics of that programming language (types, expressions, ..). I could not find a manual explaining in details how tikz as a programming language works. Could you please explain why <i> influences the result "visible" part of the list. It is always the last element

Comment: @Tengis `<i>` is a beamer syntax but TikZ understands it. It means show this item only on slide i. But your last loop runs always on the same spin of `\i` So all nodes see the same slide number and they get overprinted. Because i is only updated per the outer most spin. Maybe you would have used \z to move the position of the nodes. Is that a bit clearer?